# How can i retrive data from salesforce database?

Tags: android

I have used zkSforce library for IOS apps for retrieve data from sales-force database but now i want to retrieve data for android apps but i did not found any library similar to zkSforce and any solution so please give me any suggestion and solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check [REST API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/). It should provide you with all you need.